# Findstr failing to find string "Failures: 0"

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, wget, findstr

I am writing a little batch script on a Windows machine for automating the pulldown of failure messages and screenshots.

I have gotten to the point where once I have a list of urls, I can get what I want. However, I currently need to create these lists of urls by hand. The information I use is in a log file containing the console output of a server running a set of tests and comes in the form:

```
E:\foo\bar\three\tall\cats\testRunOutput\foobar\foosball\dogstest\Login.html
Successes: 1, Failures: 0

E:\foo\bar\three\tall\cats\testRunOutput\foodbarn\catdog\testoid\ReLogin.html
Successes: 0, Failures: 1

E:\foo\bar\three\tall\cats\testRunOutput\foobar\topdog\dogstest\Login.html
Successes: 1, Failures: 4
```

What I need is the lines above any line containing a nonzero failure (e.g. `Failures:` followed by any number of nonzero digits).

My current approach involves removing any line containing "Failures: 0" using:

```
findstr /v "Failures: 0" consoleText.txt > foo\bar\failures.txt
```

Then stripping the line above any line containing 'failures: [digits]'. Once I have a file containing these lines structured as follows:

```
E:\foo\bar\three\tall\cats\testRunOutput\foodbarn\catdog\testoid\ReLogin.html
E:\foo\bar\three\tall\cats\testRunOutput\foobar\topdog\dogstest\Login.html
```

It should be fairly simple to delete the first 41 characters of every line, Insert the beginning of the url `http://build-server:1111/job/foo/bar/testRunOutput/` and finally flip every slash.

I really only need help with

```
findstr /v "Failures: 0" consoleText.txt > foo\bar\failures.txt
```

But I thought to post the rest to provide context or get extra code in case someone had gone through this before.

I'm sorry if this is a basic question but I've mostly done command line work on Mac and Linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `find` instead of `findstr`. `find` handles spaces like any other character:

```
find "Failures: 0"
```

But what you really want:

> What I need is the lines above any line containging a nonzero failure
>   (eg. 'Failures: ' followed by any number of nonzero digits).

"Any number of nonzero digits" can be translated with "anything that starts with a nonzero digit"

```
findstr /r /c:"Failures:\ [1-9]"
```

`/r`: use Regex (`findstr` supports a very small subset of Regex)
`\`: take the following char (space) literal
`[1-9]` any of the digits 1,2,3,...9

The problem is, the line to be printed is not the line that has to be evaluated. Use a variable (`!line!`) to keep the last line:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  echo %%a|findstr /r /c:"Failures:\ [1-9]" >nul  && echo !line!
  set line=%%a
)
```

In every iteration of the loop you have `!line!` = the last processed line and `%%a` the current line. The trick is, to set `line` at the very end of the loop.)

Answer (score 0):

After further research and some, uh, creative google searches, I figured out that something I had tried earlier was sufficient. The line ended up being as follows:

```
findstr /v /c:"Failures: 0" consoleText.txt > foo\bar\failures.txt
```